# Why can't browser render this simple javascript code?

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to show a simple image in the browser with this piece of code.But it shows error saying:

> 403 error forbidden.

On more evaluation I found out that the http request sent was sent in the form

`http://localhost/test/%22http://graph.facebook.com/4/picture?type=square%22%3E%20%3C/img%3E`

which is my local webserver address. Is this a cross-site scripting issue ?

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script>
        function onclickfunction(){
            var a = document.createElement('img');
            a.src ='"http://graph.facebook.com/4/picture?type=square"';
            document.body.appendChild(a);
        }
    </script>
    <body>
        <button onclick= "onclickfunction();"> Click Me!</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why the double quoting for the src attribute?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev lol..my mistake thanks.was on another work flow

Comment: @neo Did removing the inner quotes solve the issue?

Comment: @Xufox Sure.that solved the issue.but not sure how a quote can add my local webserver address with request..weird noobie may be i'm

Comment: @SergioTulentsev can you please explain how a quote can add local/webserver address with the request ?

Comment: @neo: what happens here is that your quoted string is interpreted as a relative path, since it is not a valid absolute URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the enclosing single quotes from the URL:

```
a.src ="http://graph.facebook.com/4/picture?type=square";
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use double quotes.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function onclickfunction(){
var a = document.createElement('img');
a.src ='http://graph.facebook.com/4/picture?type=square';

document.body.appendChild(a);
}
</script>
<body>
<button onclick= "onclickfunction();"> Click Me!</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the following line

```
a.src ='"http://graph.facebook.com/4/picture?type=square"';
```

as below.

```
a.src ='http://graph.facebook.com/4/picture?type=square';
```